# about 'combine' in Kotlin Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I encountered some issues when using the combine function provided by the Flow framework to merge two Flows.

Initially, I only needed to observe one event, so I didn't use the combine function. Here's the initial version:

```kotlin
private val f = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

fun `test shared flow`(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val reach = AtomicInteger()
    val job = launch {
        f.collect {
            delay(100)
            println("consumed: $it")
            reach.getAndIncrement()
        }
    }
    delay(100)

    repeat(3) {
        val time = measureTime {
            println("emit: $it")
            f.emit(it)
        }
        println("duration: $time")
    }

    delay(500)
    assert(reach.get() == 3) { "expect 3, but got ${reach.get()}" }
    job.cancel()
}
```

You can run it here: [Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/T0yJrIrYM)

The logs produced by the above code are as follows:

```
emit: 0
duration: 4.228333ms
emit: 1
consumed: 0
duration: 106.218792ms
emit: 2
consumed: 1
duration: 105.266875ms
consumed: 2
```

Each emitted event is processed by the consumer because the onBufferOverflow parameter of MutableSharedFlow is set to BufferOverflow.SUSPEND by default. Therefore, the producer is suspended for 100 milliseconds each time it emits until the consumer completes processing.

Later, I found that the consumer needed an additional parameter when processing events. This parameter is provided by another Flow, so I used combine to merge these two Flows:

```kotlin
private val f = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
private val s = MutableStateFlow("")

fun `test shared flow`(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val reach = AtomicInteger()
    val job = launch {
        combine(s, f) { _, ff -> ff }.collect {
            println("collect: $it")
            delay(100)
            println("consumed: $it")
            reach.getAndIncrement()
        }
    }
    delay(100)
    repeat(3) {
        val time = measureTime {
            println("emit: $it")
            f.emit(it)
        }
        println("duration: $time")
    }
    delay(1000)
    assert(reach.get() == 3) { "expect 3, but got ${reach.get()}" }
    job.cancel()
}
```

You can run this code here: [Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/fSM750S6l)

Then, an issue arises with this code. If the consumer is processing an event, the producer's newly emitted events may not even be passed to the consumer:

```
emit: 0
duration: 3.889666ms
emit: 1
collect: 0
duration: 456.25us
emit: 2
duration: 98.875us
consumed: 0
collect: 2
consumed: 2
```

From the logs, it seems that the producer no longer waits for the consumer.

If I want the producer to wait for the consumer to complete processing before emitting the next event, what should I do?

All of my attempts are documented in the issue description above.